# Why is bounds checking not implemented in some of the languages?

Tags: programming-languages, implementation, buffer-overflow

According to the Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)

> Programming languages commonly associated with buffer overflows include C and C++, which provide no built-in protection against accessing or overwriting data in any part of memory and do not automatically check that data written to an array (the built-in buffer type) is within the boundaries of that array. Bounds checking can prevent buffer overflows.

So, why are 'Bounds Checking' not implemented in some of the languages like C and C++?

Comment: It's an overhead not always required.

Comment: It's an overhead that some programmers don't think is required.  The ones that never make a mistake.

Comment: @Hans, it is required when developing the application and when running unit tests; but when it is actually running, it isn't helpful, since presumably the code will already implement bounds checking as part of the logic in which it is accessed.

Comment: That would fit the category of unit testers that don't think they ever make a mistake.  They should meet and ponder why programs still have bugs.  Probably to conclude it is the user's fault.

Comment: I must be nice to be that young, @Michael.  Honest, once upon a time, that bounds-checking arithmetic was a real issue at run time.

Comment: It's an overhead some *applications* really don't need. To point fingers at programmer ignorance/arrogance is naive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, it's because it means every time you change an index, you have to do an if statement.

Let's consider a simple C for loop:

```
int ary[X] = {...};  // Purposefully leaving size and initializer unknown

for(int ix=0; ix< 23; ix++){
    printf("ary[%d]=%d\n", ix, ary[ix]);
}
```

if we have bounds checking, the generated code for `ary[ix]` has to be something like

```
LOOP:
    INC IX          ; add `1 to ix
    CMP IX, 23      ; while test
    CMP IX, X       ; compare IX and X
    JGE ERROR       ; if IX >= X jump to ERROR
    LD  R1, IX      ; put the value of IX into register 1
    LD  R2, ARY+IX  ; put the array value in R2
    LA  R3, Str42   ; STR42 is the format string
    JSR PRINTF      ; now we call the printf routine
    J   LOOP        ; go back to the top of the loop

;;; somewhere else in the code
ERROR:
    HCF             ; halt and catch fire
```

If we don't have that bounds check, then we can write instead:

```
    LD R1, IX
LOOP:
    CMP IX, 23
    JGE END
    LD R2, ARY+R1
    JSR PRINTF
    INC R1
    J   LOOP
```

This saves 3-4 instructions in the loop, which (especially in the old days) meant a lot.

In fact, in the PDP-11 machines, it was even better, because there was something called "auto-increment addressing".  On a PDP, all of the register stuff etc turned into something like

```
CZ  -(IX), END    ; compare IX to zero, then decrement; jump to END if zero
```

(And anyone who happens to remember the PDP better than I do, don't give me trouble about the precise syntax etc; you're an old fart like me, you know how these things slip away.)

Comment: Sure.  Hell, it was done in Algol-60.  It was an overhead then too.  When Kernighan, Ritchie, Thompson et al built C and UNIX, they opted *not* to do it to save all those instructions for their own nefarious purposes.

When Jim Gosling and the Oak guys built proto-Java, they decided that had been a mistake -- ergo bounds-checking.

Comment: You're probably overstating it. For your particular example, for example, any optimizing compiler would be able to hoist the comparison outside of the loop.

Comment: Charlie - With CPU speeds getting better doesn't it make sense to implement the bounds checking and make it the default option. When I update a Windows or an Ubuntu OS, I see that a lot of the patches are related to buffer overflow.

Comment: @ergosys Optimizing compiler?  For C? In 1970? T'ain't no such animal.

Comment: @Praveen, it does, but that'd be a different language; there are perverse C tricks that usefully take advantage of this flexibility, and would break if the compiler suddenly became bounds checked.  Also, remember the C pointer/array duality: how can you compile a program that uses an `extern int **` as a two dimensional array that's malloc-ed in another file?  PL/I, one of C's direct ancestors, had bounds checking.  Google "PL/I dope vector" for details.

Comment: @Charlie Martin, That's probably true, but it wasn't clear you were talking about a specific time period, it sounded like you were making a blanket statement.

Comment: @ergosys it *is* a blanket statement -- about what C is designed the way it is. People forget that we always live with the constraints built into our languages when they were designed.

Answer (score 4):

It is easier to implement and faster both to compile and at run-time. It also simplifies the language definition (as quite a few things can be left out if this is skipped).

Currently, when you do:

```
int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
*p = 50;
```

C (and C++) just says, "Okey dokey! I'll put something in that spot in memory".

If bounds checking were required, C would have to say, "Ok, first let's see if I can put something there? Has it been allocated? Yes? Good. I'll insert now." By skipping the test to see whether there is something which can be written there, you are saving a very costly step. On the other hand, (she wore a glove), we now live in an era where "optimization is for those who cannot afford RAM," so the arguments about the speed are getting much weaker.

Answer (score 3):

It's all about the performance. However, the assertion that C and C++ have no bounds checking is not entirely correct. It is quite common to have "debug" and "optimized" versions of each library, and it is not uncommon to find bounds-checking enabled in the debugging versions of various libraries.

This has the advantage of quickly and painlessly finding out-of-bounds errors when developing the application, while at the same time eliminating the performance hit when running the program for realz.

I should also add that the performance hit is non-negigible, and many languages other than C++ will provide various high-level functions operating on buffers that are implemented directly in C and C++ specifically to avoid the bounds checking. For example, in Java, if you compare the speed of copying one array into another using pure Java vs. using System.arrayCopy (which does bounds checking once, but then straight-up copies the array without bounds-checking each individual element), you will see a decently large difference in the performance of those two operations.

Answer (score 2):

The primary reason is the performance overhead of adding bounds checking to C or C++.  While this overhead can be reduced substantially with state-of-the-art techniques (to 20-100% overhead, depending upon the application), it is still large enough to make many folks hesitate.  I'm not sure whether that reaction is rational -- I sometimes suspect that people focus too much on performance, simply because performance is quantifiable and measurable -- but regardless, it is a fact of life.  This fact reduces the incentive for major compilers to put effort into integrating the latest work on bounds checking into their compilers.

A secondary reason involves concerns that bounds checking might break your app.  Particularly if you do funky stuff with pointer arithmetic and casting that violate the standard, bounds checking might block something your application is currently doing.  Large applications sometimes do amazingly crufty and ugly things.  If the compiler breaks the application, then there's no point in pointing blaming the crufty code for the problem; people aren't going to keep using a compiler that breaks their application.

Another major reason is that bounds checking competes with [ASLR](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/ASLR) + [DEP](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention).  ASLR + DEP are perceived as solving, oh, 80% of the problem or so.  That reduces the perceived need for full-fledged bounds checking.

Answer (score 1):

Because it would cripple those *general purpose* languages for HPC requirements. There are plenty of applications where buffer overflows really do not matter one iota, simply because they do not happen. Such features are much better off in a library (where in fact you can already find examples for C/C++). 
For domain specific languages it may make sense to bake such features into the language definition and trade the resulting performance hit for increased security.