# C++ Detect dangling pointers when they are going out of bound without knowing the size

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, null

Consider piece of code

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
        int *arrPtr = new int[4];
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
                arrPtr[i]=i*2;


        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
                arrPtr++;
                cout<<"arrPtr ["<<i<<"]\t"<<*arrPtr<<endl;
        }
        cout<<endl;
        return 0; }
```

When I compile this program

> g++ main.cpp -o main && ./main

It gives me

```
arrPtr [0]  2
arrPtr [1]  4
arrPtr [2]  6
arrPtr [3]  0
arrPtr [4]  135145
arrPtr [5]  0
arrPtr [6]  0
arrPtr [7]  0
arrPtr [8]  0
arrPtr [9]  0
```

I want to be able to detect (throw or check) when arrPtr is not pointing to "valid" element.
In the code above last valid element is arrPtr[3].

No "Me Too" answers please!

Comment: You can't. Just pass the size along, in one form or another. E.g. use `std::vector` instead of plain arrays (and access it via `v.at(i)` instead of `v[i]`).

Comment: @atzz oops saw your comment after posting..

Comment: Note that if you have an array of values (not a dynamically allocated pointer), it is always possible to get the size by doing `sizeof(array)/sizeof(type_of_array)`. That said, you obviously need the homogenous type to calculate this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `vector`.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a(4);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        a[i] = i * 2;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << i << ": " << a.at(i) << std::endl;
}
```

Result:

```
0: 0
1: 2
2: 4
3: 6
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
Aborted
```

Comment: No thats the thing, I am not suppose to use vectors as I am working on generic framework. User may use `MyClass *c=new MyClass[]'

Comment: @mkhan3189: then you're stuck. Bounds checking cannot be done portably, except by `std::vector`.

Comment: @mkhan3189 What is not generic about using vectors? This is the way to go, period.

Comment: @mkhan3189 Have you considered taking iterators in your own functions (same as the standard library functions)? This work with vectors, arrays, or really any container.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Problem is that I have template that is taking void* in one of the functions. and I know that void pointer is an array (because user will always pass array). Now I am trying to find the size of array being passed. One technique I used is:
T *currElement = static_cast<T*>(voidPtr);
and then currElement++ but obviously I wouldn't be sure when to stop moving to next address.

Comment: @mkhan3189: it's impossible to find out the size of an array from only a pointer to the beginning. That's why standard template algorithms always take *two* pointers (or, in general, iterators).

Comment: @mkhan3189 Any technique you used for that is wrong, sorry. It simply isn't possible in C++, and no matter what you try, there will be cases where it doesn't work. It cannot work in the general case, because the same pointer value could simultaneously point to different arrays of different lengths (if two arrays of different lengths appear in a union). And it likely won't work in practise, because there will often be addressable memory after the end of the array.

Comment: @hvd This makes a lot of sense. I guess I have to change the base. 

Any way for anyone saying "use std::vector" if I write function and I use it I always use std::vector but this is something I am expecting user to pass on. for instance you cannot ask user to pass vector when you are writing overloaded operator delete[] because you know user is possibily going to use MyClass *classname=new MyClass[100]; instead of std::vector<MyClass*> c well thanks for the comments. By Far this std::vector has been great answer although doesn't work in my case but I am marking this as answer

Answer (score 2):

Others have shown the solution for this concrete problem: use `std::vector` instead of raw pointers (do this anyway!) and element access via `.at()`.

However, in general you should simply make sure that the situation never arises in your code. Out of bounds errors are not situations that you should handle at runtime, they are **bugs** in your code and need to be removed beforehand.

There are several strategies for that – for instance, don’t use indexed access. Most such instances can be replaced by iterator access which, although not automatically safe, makes it much harder to make errors.

Better yet, avoid loops where possible and use higher-order algorithms from the C++ standard library instead.

As an example what a loop-less code could look like:

```
std::vector<int> arr;
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(arr), 4,
    [] {
        static int current = 0;
        return current++ * 2;
    });
std::copy(begin(arr), end(arr), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

This style takes some getting used to but it drastically reduces the opportunity to make errors in code, and renders some error classes impossible a propri.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible with plain C-arrays. You can use std::vector, which has API for elements access with bounds checking.

Answer (score 0):

This topic has been widely discussed. Generally, in C-language, it's not possible to detect whether a pointer is pointing to a place in an array without knowing some information of the array in advance.

As @Charlie Martin mentioned in his answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410296/why-is-bounds-checking-not-implemented-in-some-of-the-languages), this is because the boundary-check will cost additional operations. As C is commonly used to make speed-sensitive programs(such as hardware driver), boundary-checking is not implemented in the language, but by people who needs it himself.

So, if you want to do the boundary-check, you have to do something like :

```
int *start = new int[4];
int size=4;
int *arrPtr;
...
for (int i=0,arrPtr=start;i<10;i++){
    arrPtr++;
    if(arrPtr>=start && arrPtr <start+size) // the boundary checking by yourself
       cout<<"arrPtr ["<<i<<"]\t"<<*arrPtr<<endl;
}
```

In this way the language can let you to decide whether it's worth and necessary to use the additional operations to do the boundary-checking.

And of course, once you decide that you need the boundary-checking in your program, there're already-implemented higher-level data types such as `vector`.