# Why is different behavior shown for same code in C and Java?

Tags: java, c

In C, the code snippet:

```
int i;
    double x[10];
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        x[i] = (double) i;
        printf("%f\n", x[i]);
    }
```

produces the following output:

```
0.000000
1.000000
2.000000
3.000000
4.000000
5.000000
6.000000
7.000000
8.000000
9.000000
10.000000
```

However, in Java the code snippet(same code) just syntactically different:

```
int i;
        double[] x = new double[10];
        for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            x[i] = (double) i;
            System.out.printf("%f\n", x[i]);
        }
```

produces the following output:

```
0.000000
1.000000
2.000000
3.000000
4.000000
5.000000
6.000000
7.000000
8.000000
9.000000
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at Array.main(Array.java:14)
```

Why does the C compiler not flag the attempt to access outside the array bounds?
Am I missing something here?

Comment: In both cases, it's not the compiler checking bounds. That happens at runtime (in Java) or not at all (in C).

Comment: you loop should work from 0 to 9.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410296/why-is-bounds-checking-not-implemented-in-some-of-the-languages

Comment: The duplicate asks explicitly about C++. This question asks about the differences between C and Java. That is only partially and indirectly addressed by the duplicate. Voting to re-open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java has array bounds checking, C doesn't. In Java you get a runtime exception when you access index 10, in C you get *undefined behaviour*. In this case, you wrote `10.0` to some place you're not allowed too, but through sheer bad luck, the program ran to completion.

Also note that java arrays have a `length` property, which makes it easy to avoid this kind of mistake. In the C case, it is possible to get the length of the array by careful use of the `sizeof` operator. But the fact that often pointers are used instead of arrays (e.g. when you "pass" an array to a function that takes a pointer to an element of an array) means often the size information is not readily available.

Comment: Is it really undefined when writing (except for the minor detail of what exactly you are overwriting when doing that)?

Comment: @Thilo Yes, it is undefined. It is too complicated to specify what is supposed to happen in this case, without adding the overhead of a bounds checking system.

Answer (score 0):

In C, we can access the element that is not initialize to that variable. In java we cannot
do that. It strictly check the array of bounds.

> Java performs bounds checking every time an element in an array is
>   accessed. Bounds checking is where an access to an array index is
>   checked against the size of the array – and an exception is thrown if
>   that array index is out of bounds, and larger than the size of the
>   array.

C does not perform the bounds checking.