# Are normal Arrays also dynamic?

Tags: c, arrays

The following is my code in C

```
main(){

    int a[1];
    a[0]=10;
    a[1]=12;
    printf("%d\n",a[1]);
    copy_arr(a);
    printf("%d",a[1]);
}
```

The following is the output

```
12
12
```

Shouldn't it give array out of bound or something like this?

Or does the code above depend on the compiler?

I am running the above in a gcc compiler.

Comment: `main()` should be `int main(void)`, and you need `#include <stdio.h>` at the top. Where is `copy_arr` defined?

Comment: The compiler *should* give you a warning that your array access is out of bounds, and the clang compiler *does* warn you. Not sure why gcc doesn't.

Comment: With *gcc*, be sure to enable warnings with `-Wall -Wextra` compiler flags.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7410296/694576

Comment: @user3386109 The compiler could figure it out in this particular case. But in most real life scenarios, the indexing is based on some runtime information.

Answer (score 4):

There's no automatic array bounds checking in C. Your code has *undefined behaviour* (UB). This means it can sometimes seem to "work". But you can't rely on any particular outcome. A program with UB is a broken program.

Answer (score 3):

Accessing out-of-bound memory is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Be it statically allocated or dynamically.

Point to note: `C` does not have any *in-built* feature of checking out-of-bound array access. So, you'll not be *warned* by default [as you *might* have expected].

Answer (score 2):

```
int a[1];
```

This array can just hold a single integer and the valid access is `a[0]` , `a[1]` will be array out of bound access which is undefined behvaior.

Comment: @alk I meant the results are not consistent and it might work sometimes and might not sometimes